# Configurable Product not showing in product page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have an issue with Configurable product are not showing in product page

I had look to system.log

I found this error

main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Swatches\ViewModel\Product\Renderer\Configurable does not exist [] []

Actually I went to config.php to check if there are extension disabled.
'Magento_ConfigurableProduct' => 1,
'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales' => 1,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct' => 1,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi' => 1,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer' => 1,
'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable' => 1,

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

I also have this error:

main.INFO: Reference to undeclared plugin with name 'ddg_customer_sendNewAccountEmail_disabler'. [] []

Regards,

Comment: Did you install some custom module? If yes, try disabling it and then try again.

Comment: I don't know I have too many extension installed on the website. how I can trace the issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, the second one is pretty straightforward, that plugin is either declared in `di.xml` and not implemented or could be other way round. For the Configurable Product issue, see if that file path given in error actually exists or not. If it exists, then maybe some custom extension is playing with it at some place which is causing this error. Also try running all required commands in case you haven't.